# Can Apple Pay be used without an internet connection?

Tags: iphone, apple-watch, apple-pay

Can Apple Pay, on an *iPhone*, be used without an internet connection (no cellular data and no WIFI)?

Can Apple Pay, on an *Apple Watch*, be used without a connection to the phone?